# Can't get dynamic text to show update in flash, but trace works

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm using text that is set to "dynamic text".

In actionscript 3 I tried:

```
    instancename.text = "abc";
    trace(instancename.text);
```

Trace returns "abc" when I test the movie but the appearance of the text doesn't change.

In action script 2 I tried:

```
    var1 = "abc";
    instance1._text = "def";
    trace(var1 + instance1._text);
```

Trace returns "abcdef" when I test the movie but the appearance of the text doesn't change.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by appearance of text, do you want formatting of text?

Comment: Is the textfield set up properly in the timeline? As in the size is big enough to see, fonts are correct, color is correct, etc etc. It sounds more like a problem there.

Comment: Embedding fonts was all that was needed to fix this...

Comment: Yes, embedding is def. the solution.. 1 more tip to save time later in case this wasn't the case for anyone else.... If the text field is rotated at all I have found that it won't display either for some reason... but that may have been fixed a while ago, I did flash a longgggg time ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In actionscript 2, your lines should be

```
var1 = "abc";
instance1.text = "def";
trace(var1 + instance1.text);
```

(remove the _ char)

Moreover, try with

```
instance1.htmlText = "def";
```

this depends on how you have setup your textfield box.

Another important consideration: make sure that you have embedded the font in the textfield (Embed... button in Properties palette)

Comment: Yeah I just had to do what that output warning kept saying and embed the fonts. BTW if I started with the initial text of "abc" and used instance1.text = "cba"; it works because it already knows those letters.

Answer (score 1):

Try with a very, very basic approach, such as this:

```
var t:TextField = new TextField;
t.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
t.text = "hello world";
this.addChild( t );

trace( "hello world" );
```

If that works, then your problem is elsewhere. Some things to check:

- Is the TextField added to the stage?
- Is there anything covering the TextField?
- Are you using embedded fonts (in which case that's a whole different problem)?

Put a border and a background colour on your TextField:

```
t.border = true;
t.background = true;
t.backgroundColor = 0xff000;
```

and see if you see that

Comment: Hi I'm using the text tool to define where the text is and its initial string, etc. I just want to use one line of code to change the string. Anyway when I embed the fonts things work fine.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to go to embed... (near the character adjustment under the fonts selector) font and check inside the boxes which you want it to display then press OK and try again. I had the same problem but now it works!

Comment: please post a possible answer here.